# AllJoyn Thin sending signals to all joined sessions

Tags: alljoyn

I am trying to send a Change of value Signal to all sessions my alljoyn thin app is connected to using :

```
AJ_MarshalSignal(&Bus, &sig_out, SIGNAL_ STATECHANGED, NULL, 0, AJ_FLAG_GLOBAL_BROADCAST, 0);
```

However the Clients (running on AJSCL) are not able to receive the Signal.

But when I send it to a particular session using :

```
AJ_MarshalSignal(&Bus, &sig_out, SIGNAL_ STATECHANGED, NULL, session_ID, AJ_FLAG_GLOBAL_BROADCAST, 0);
```

The Client with the specified `session_ID` is able to receive it.

Is there any flag in the Thin Client Version similar to the

```
BusAttachment.SESSION_ID_ALL_HOSTED
```

I do not want to send it as a Sessionless Signal. Is there any other way all the joined session can receive the Signal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SESSION_ID_ALL_HOSTED functionality is not implemented in thin client. You should implement the logic to sessioncast to each connected client yourself.

If you’re using version 15.09 and up, the thin client code base helps you somewhat: AJ_BusAttachment.sessions is a linked list of AJ_Session structures, where each AJ_Session describes an ongoing session. If you iterate through this list and emit the signal for each session where AJ_Session->host != 0, you have equivalent behavior to SESSION_ID_ALL_HOSTED.

- As received from the Allseen Alliance Core mailing List